# polymer-element attributes attribute in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

In Polymer.js, I can do this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="test-element" attributes="word" noscript>
  <template>Foo {{word}} <content></content></template>
</polymer-element>

<test-element word="bar">baz</test-element>
```

And the output is `Foo bar baz`. See http://jsfiddle.net/vV3yS/.

However, if I do the same in Polymer.dart, I just get `Foo baz`. Worse, if I add `lightdom`, it works in Polymer.js, but Polymer.dart gives `bazFoo`.

Can I make Polymer.dart behave the same as Polymer.js does? I'm using 0.9.5.

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting because `lightdom` was already removed from Polymer.js a while ago (https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/243)

It's a while since I used `noscript` myself but my experience was that it has issues in PolymerDart especially when you extend other elements.
I guess your element would work if you add a script to your element with a field

```dart
@published var word;
```

The link to the issue you created for this problem:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17426

**EDIT**
polymer-element with attributes but without a script (with `noscript`) wasn't supported previous to Polymer 0.10.0 but should be supported with the next release (https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17426)

Comment: I hope Dart doesn't remove lightdom. It has been useful. Regarding noscript, sure, I can create a class and it will work, but that class needs an @CustomTag, a published property for each attribute and a constructor to call super.created(). That's a lot of repeated code that should be redundant when I want quite a few of these lightweight elements.

Comment: I'm sure they will remove it soon. Yes there is some boilerplate but I didn't encounter many situations where a custom element without code could be very useful. The issue you created was the right thing to do. The script is only a workaround though until it is fixed.